# Common legend for subplot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm creating a plot using matplotlib and it seems that I stucked with one problem.
I draw 3 subplots and I want to get common legend for all of them

```
fig, (ax, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)
ax.plot(FRAME1['T1'],FRAME1['Num'], marker = 'o', label='1')
ax2.plot(FRAME3['T1'],FRAME3['Num'], marker = 'o', label='2',color='r')
ax2.plot(FRAME4['T1'],FRAME4['Num'], marker = 'o', label='3',color='turquoise')
ax3.plot(FRAME2['T1'],FRAME2['Num'], marker = 'o', label='4',color='g')

ax.set_ylim(-118, -116.5)  
ax3.set_ylim(-136, -135)

plt.legend( (ax,ax2,ax3),loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=[0, 1],
           ncol=2, shadow=True, title="Legend", fancybox=True)
```

I have used the legend instance but it shows legen only on the last subplot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you need to show the legend on one of the subplots. It's your decision which one you chose.

In order to show all four lines in the legend, you need to provide a reference to the lines to the legend

```
plt.legend(handles = [line1, line2, ...])
```

See also the [Matplotlib legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html).
So here is a working example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(0,12,size=(12,4))
y = np.random.randint(0,8,size=(12,4))

fig, (ax, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(5,5))

l, = ax.plot(x[:,0],y[:,0], marker = 'o', label='1')
l2, =ax2.plot(x[:,1],y[:,1], marker = 'o', label='2',color='r')
l3, =ax2.plot(x[:,2],y[:,2], marker = 'o', label='3',color='turquoise')
l4, =ax3.plot(x[:,3],y[:,3], marker = 'o', label='4',color='g')


plt.legend( handles=[l, l2, l3, l4],loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=[0, 1],
           ncol=2, shadow=True, title="Legend", fancybox=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]